# How to Order by in listagg

Tags: sql, oracle

If I write a simple query, then orakle gives the correct data

```
SELECT NUMBER FROM myNumbers WHERE user = '11111' ORDER BY length(NUMBER) ASC;
```

[image]

but I need to use the listagg function,
in order to continue to throw several options of numbers.
my new statement looks like this

```
SELECT listagg(NUMBER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LENGTH(NUMBER)  ASC) AS MANY_NUMBERS
FROM myNumbers WHERE user = '11111'' AND ROWNUM < 4;
```

[image]
but in this Statement the ORDER BY does not work. The data is not "sorted" and the data is not displayed correctly

Comment: added pictures for understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries you used aren't the same.

First query should be an inline view for the second, because the 2nd doesn't have `ORDER BY` clause (as the 1st one) so `ROWNUM < 4` returned who-knows-which rows.

```
SELECT listagg(NUMBER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LENGTH(NUMBER)  ASC) AS MANY_NUMBERS
from (SELECT NUMBER FROM myNumbers WHERE user = '11111' ORDER BY length(NUMBER) ASC)
where rownum < 4;
```

---

Or, I'd rather suggest something like this (I rename columns as names you used are reserved for datatype and Oracle function):

```
SQL> with mynumbers (cuser, num) as
  2    (select '11111', 8246    from dual union all
  3     select '11111', 8246    from dual union all
  4     select '11111', 5002647 from dual union all
  5     select '11111', 5002748 from dual union all
  6     select '11111', 5002750 from dual union all
  7     select '11111', 5003078 from dual union all
  8     select '11111', 5002226 from dual
  9    ),
 10  temp as
 11    (select num,
 12            row_number() over (partition by cuser order by length(num), num) rn
 13     from mynumbers
 14     where cuser = '11111'
 15    )
 16  select listagg(num, ', ') within group (order by rn) many_numbers
 17  from temp
 18  where rn < 4;

MANY_NUMBERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8246, 8246, 5002226

SQL>
```